# Problem with using OpenCV library in Android Dynamic Shared library and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, opencv, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the OpenCV library for android (native C++) with Xamarin.Forms application. I created a Dynamic Shared Library and its wrapper in C# that works when there is no OpenCV in the project.

Next, I configured my library project to use OpenCV and built it (without actually using OpenCV in my code). The build is successful, but now when I run my Xamarin application and call functions from c++, this exception is thrown:

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'libMathFuncs.so assembly: type: member:(null)'

I followed the instructions described [here](https://github.com/xamcat/mobcat-samples/tree/master/cpp_with_xamarin#writing-the-managed-library-code), successfully created a .so file, and used it in Xamarin.Forms application. I wrote the whole process in my [blog](https://rbahrami.github.io/p/xamarin.forms-and-c-/).

Then I did the following changes to my Dynamic Shared Library project configuration (in Visual Studio):

In General -> Use of STL : LLVM libc++ static library (c++_static)   (also tried shared library)

***In C++:***

1. General -> Aditional Include Library: Add "PathToOpenCV\sdk\native\jni\include" (I also tried to add this
2. path to VC++ Directories -> External Include Directories)
3. set the **Enable C++ Exceptions** to **Yes (-fexceptions)**
4. set the **Enable Run-Time Type Information** to **Yes (-frtti)**
5. set the **Precompile Header** to **Not Using Precompiled Headers**

***In Linker:***

I tried two ways:

Way 1: I added "sdk\native\libs\arm64-v8a\libopencv_java4.so" to input -> Aditional Dependencies

Way 2:

1. Added "sdk\native\libs\arm64-v8a" to General -> Additional Library Directories and
2. Added "opencv_java4" to Input -> Library Dependencies

I didn't use any OpenCV in my code (Actually did at first, but remove them). The project is built successfully.
But now when the application calls the function from .so file, the above exception will be thrown.

I tried with or without changing the told flags, but the result was the same.

Note: For now I only intrested in ARM64

---

My environment:

- Visual Studio 2022
- Xamarin.Forms (Android Only)
- Target API Level: Pie 9.0 (android-28)
- Android NDK: R23C
- Target: Nokia 8.1 - Android 11

There is code in [GitHub](https://github.com/redcurry/GreenTea) that is similar to what I want to do. I compared the project configuration and code of this repo with my project but didn't find where I went wrong.

Comment: This is a very old problem in xamarin.android, and I found a [link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4772) about this error, I hope it can help you solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. In the link is said that the bug is fixed in VS 2019 version 16.17. I'm using VS 2022 with the latest update, and apparently, that bug is only related to Android 5.